# Not sampling at 5 ms when I increase NREADINGS to 2 in the Oscilloscope application (TinyOS)

Tags: tinyos

In the TinyOS Oscilloscope application on micaz motes, when I set the sampling rate to 5 ms with `NREADINGS = 1`, I notice the blinking of the green LED going really fast. But when I set `NREADINGS = 2` and sampling rate to 5 ms, I notice the blinking becomes slower which means I am sending fewer packets than in the previous case. Is there any way I can get the blinking to be faster, that is, can I do something to increase the number of packets I send at `NREADINGS = 2` and sampling rate equal to 5 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sampling rate determines how often the Oscilloscope application samples a sensor. `NREADINGS` determines how many samples the application obtains before it sends them in a radio packet. LED blinks each time the application sends a packet. Therefore, if you increase `NREADINGS` from `1` to `2`, it will blink approximately every 10 ms instead of 5 ms (every two samples).

If you want to send packets with the same frequency when you increase `NREADINGS`, at the same you have to decrease the sampling interval. Note, however, that sampling a sensor as well as sending a packet takes some time, so there are some constraints on how fast the application can work.

Comment: Yes that is helpful and makes a lot of sense . Thank you !